# File possibly 'corrupted' after copying using rsync command in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-outlook, rsync, ubuntu-14.04, file-extension

I used rsync to copy a 19.2GB .pst file (Outlook files extension) from an old hard drive to a new one using `rsync -avzPSX Outlook\ Files.pst /media/new_drive`. I read that the -z option compresses the file (now 16.2 GB) from the source and decompress the file at the target folder, but when i'm trying to use my file on my new drive i think there's a problem with the file extension, it says that is a .tar file but the name is Outlook Files.pst.... is the '.pst' part of the name of the new file? ('Outlook Files.pst'.tar)? i tried to change it the name removing the .pst from it and then unzip it/"untar" using `tar -xvf Outlook Files.pst` command but i get an error almost when the process is about to finish.

> Wrote only 8192 of 10240 bytes
>
> Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>
> tar: Unexpected EOF in archive tar:

And now the file from the source is a .tar file too so i don't know how to undo this or what should i do... Just checked it with `file Outlook Files.pst` both, source and target files and returns

> Outlook Files.pst: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

Additionally, when u try to run `tar xvf` i get an image.dd file, can this help me to get the file correctly?
Thank you.